# How to query for "Yesterday, in my timezone" when all my timestamps are UTC

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to include, in my where clause, a way to automatically pull data for the previous day based on my current timezone. All of my data is stored with a UTC timestamp.

I can change my timestamp from UTC to my timezone ("America/Chicago") and I can automatically pull data for the last X days; for example, for the prior week, without having to manually enter a date. But I cannot figure out how to do both simultaneously in my where clause.

```
SELECT *  
FROM `my-data-set` 
WHERE
event_time >= CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS TIMESTAMP)
AND event_time < CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

I would like to be able to look at the previous week or day in my timezone, not the previous UTC day.

Comment: Incidentally, using '-' within a table/column identifier is a fantastically bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do specify the timezone:

```
where date(event_time, 'America/Chicago') = date_add(current_date, interval -1 day)
```

Note that the parentheses are not needed for `current_date`.

The key to the logic is converting the UTC timestamp to a date in your local time.

Comment: Simple, easy, and I'm wondering how I didn't realize I needed to convert the event_time first like that. Thanks so much this works perfectly!